# Problema con html dinamico en una llamada ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

resulta que tengo html dinámico que se carga de una llamada ajax a un php, ese html trae x registros según una categoria, el problema es super raro y es que siempre el primer registro que trae el ajax no le funciona el botón los demás si, esto nunca me había pasado y no tengo ni idea.
este es el código html dinámico.

```js
<?php
 
include "conexion.php";
$varcat = $_POST["cat"];
$sql1= "select id,subcategoria from categorias where categoria='$varcat'  ";
$query = $con->query($sql1);
?>
<?php if($query->num_rows>0):?>
<?php while ($persona=$query->fetch_array()):?>
        <input class="btn btn-default" type='submit' value='<?php echo $persona['subcategoria'] ?>' id="cat-<?php echo $persona['id'] ?>" style="font-weight: bold;border:none" />
        
 <script>
 
          $('#cat-<?php echo $persona["id"];?>').on("click",function(){
 
     document.getElementById("filtro").innerHTML="";
  subcat = $(this).val();
alert(subcat);
  var url = "filtradox.php"; 
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
   
         url: url,
         data:{subcat:subcat},
         
      
         success: function(data)
         {
   
    $("#filtro").html(data);
         }
       });
    return false;
 });
  </script>
<?php  endwhile;?>
<?php else:?>
  <p class="alert alert-warning">No hay productos que mostrar</p>
   <?php endif;
?>
```

Comment: Buenas, la verdad que no se me ocurre xq ocurre lo que comentas, ya que es extraño que el primero no funcione y el resto si. Lo que se me ocurre es que en lugar de usar Id uses una clase para esos botones, ya que visto lo visto solo te interesa el valor del input y lo declaras una sola vez.

Comment: Puede haber alguna valor extraño en el `id` como `_` o `@`?